# Add new element to the list

Tags: c++

I have singly-linked list, and I want to add a new element to this structure.

---

In procedural code I would create structure, and head pointer pointing to NULL. This is how I resolved this in oo code:

```
typedef struct a {
    int element;
    struct a *next;
} a;
typedef struct b {
    int element;
    struct b *next;
} b;

class Foo {
    a *a; // head for a structure = NULL at the beginning
    b *b; // head for b structure = NULL at the beginning
```

The next thing I would do is checking if the list is empty, and if is, set head to point to the newly created first element.

The function doing this should be template, because I want to pass to it any structure I have. So:

```
template <class T> void Addition_Struct::add(T head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));

        head->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

And a couple of problems appear at this moment. I guess that T should be the type of a structure, and head the head pointer (NULL currently). The compiler throws an error in malloc line - `cannot convert "a**" to "a*"`. What's wrong?

EDIT:

Sample function call would be:

```
add(this->a);
```

Comment: Why tag it "c" when you are using C++. Then why are you using `malloc` and not `new``?

Comment: How are yyou calling `convertToStack`?

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot to change my code - edited, sorry.

Comment: @Ed Heal - because I kind of have to do write the thing in C, but using C++ classes.

Comment: @user2252786 - If you can use C++ then use new. Either way make up your mind zs to the language you are using.

Comment: Still - new T(sizeof(T)) displays the same thing.

Comment: ``new T(sizeof(T))`  - Try `new T;` might even compile

Comment: It doesnt, displays same thing.

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that it doesn't ever recognize "a" data type inside of this method.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the meaning of `T` in your template function.

In your sample call `add(this->a);`, you are considering the parameter to be a **pointer to a struct**.

But your function `head = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));` considers `T` to be the struct type.  Not a pointer.

Change your template declaration to clarify that `T` is the type *pointed to*.

```
template <class T> void Addition_Struct::add(T * head)
```